# Error in R programming for large data sets

Tags: r

I have collapsed the below data frame based on Unit price

```
Material Unit Price Document.Date
 500       4.28       2017-08-18
 500       5.00       2018-06-07
```

I have used the code as

```
library(data.table)
Data$newdate<-strptime(Data$Document.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
df_orig <- as.data.table(Data)
d=df_orig[ , newdate := as.Date(newdate,format="%m/%d/%Y")][order(newdate)]
e=d[, .(newvar = paste(Unit Price, collapse="/")), by=.(Material)]
e$newvar1=gsub("[/]"," > ",e$newvar)  #to replace "/" with " > "
e$newvar=NULL
e$newvar2=sapply(str_extract_all(gsub("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:\\s+>\\s+\\1\\b)+", "\\1", e$newvar1), "\\d+\\.\\d+"), paste, collapse=" > ")
e$newvar1=NULL
```

I get the output as expected like

```
Material  newvar2
 500      4.28 > 5
```

But if the same values are there in Large data sets, I get the below output(for the same code). That is 5 is missing. May I know Why?

```
 Material  newvar2
  500      4.28
```

Comment: Rroaring, your data and code are inconsistent: for example, you titled it `Document.Date` but seem to refer to it as `newdate`. Can you update your code to better represent variable names so that there is no confusion? (Suggest you quickly look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for markdown editing.) I suspect that your top frame might not be what is loaded into `df_orig`, since your `format=` is not close to what your data transformation needs.

Comment: This will be a lot easier to answer if you can show an example of the data where it doesn't work as you expected. Otherwise it's like saying "Here is a word that is spelled correctly. Spellcheck tells me some other words in a large data set are spelled incorrectly. Can you fix them?"

Comment: Hi Evans, Edited

Comment: Hi Jon, I Know :) But i cannot paste the entire datasets here.:(

Comment: Suggestions please:)

Comment: I thing I can tell is when collapse fucntion is applied to large datasets, i see improper execution in the middle. Why?